Lyx Windows Installer blocked by Microsoft Defender
When I tried to install Lyx 2.4.1 (downloaded from the official website), the installer was blocked by the Microsoft Defender, the message shown was as follows:

Microsoft Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from
starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.
App:  LyX-241-Installer-1-x64.exe  Publisher:   Unknown publisher

I tried to install previous versions including 2.3.8 and 2.4.0, the same problem persists. But when I open the installer of 2.3.7 (the version I'm currently using), the problem didn't show up.
Does anyone else encounter the same problem?

This is quite normal for open source projects what does not have the money to pay for a signature (or what ever that thing is called). Usually there is an option to run it anyways.

Thanks, just want to know whether this happens to others.
